# Manipulation java 8 spring-data-jpa streams out of a transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

In spring app, I know that, `Spring-data-jpa` streams cannot be manipulated out of the transaction, because the driver closes the connection once the transaction exit.

But what I want to know that, what happens if I don't put the `@Transactional` spring annotation, because it seems the connection still alive for the controller to manipulate.

This is the Service class:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Transactional
    public Stream<User> getUsersStreamFromDb() {
        return userRepo.findAllStream();
    }

    public Stream<User> getUsersStreamFromDbWithNoTransactionalAnnot() {
        return userRepo.findAllStream();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Stream<User> getUsersStreamFromService() {
        return userRepo.findAll().stream();
    }
}
```

And the Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/db")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUsersDb() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(manipulateStream(userService.getUsersStreamFromDb()));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/db-notrans")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUsersDbNoTransactionl() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(manipulateStream(userService.getUsersStreamFromDbWithNoTransactionalAnnot()));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/service")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUsersService() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(manipulateStream(userService.getUsersStreamFromService()));
    }

    private User[] manipulateStream(Stream<User> users) {
        return users.filter(u -> u.getFName().contains("3")).toArray(User[]::new);
    }
}
```

The **first method** `getUsersDb` fails (connection closed) which is expected.

the **second method** `getUsersDbNoTransactionl` doesn't fail, Is this because the transaction span the whole layers from the controller back to the controller? (I need in-depth explanation here)

the **third method** `getUsersService` will success of course.

complete code is here:
https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/test-jpa-streams

Comment: I wrote this blog post trying to put things I understood so far together http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2016/09/my-thoughts-about-spring-transactions.html.